# Error when installing gems, using WSL Windows 10 Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems

I am using Windows 10 WSL ubuntu and am trying to install gems.

`ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why: Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - timed out (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)`

Is the message I get after typing `gem install rails`

I have disabled IPv6 and it still does not work

Comment: Can you ping `https://rubygems.org`? Can you ping Google?

Comment: try restarting your computer. I think this happened to me when I canceled turning off my computer. Restarting my windows computer fixed it for me

Comment: This is the result of me pinging api.rubygems.org

{PING api.rubygems.org(2a04:4e42:200::70 (2a04:4e42:200::70)) 56 data bytes
^C
--- api.rubygems.org ping statistics ---
143 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 401847ms}